# Unique permission for document library which contains more than threshold documents

Tags: 2013, permissions, sharepoint-addin, list-view-threshold

I have document library which contails 6000 docs and threshold limit is 5000. I am facing below eror while trying to give unique permission for that library. Please suggest. I do not have server access.[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can do, except increase the threshold on Central Admin.

However, that 5000 is there for a very good reason, especially if you have 5000 items with unique permissions on the list. I strongly recommend dividing content into multiple lists to prevent serious performance issues.

[This](http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/02/understanding-list-query-throttling.html) document describes how threshold can be modified in Central Admin.